# Autoware - Sharing files between the host system and ADE

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I am new to Autoware, and trying to install the Autoware in my system by following the steps given [here](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation-ade.html).

I have a question in section **Sharing files between the host system and ADE**.
In the given example, first step is to move the file from host (local) system home folder to `adehome` folder. (Which effectively deletes the folder in the host home folder. And then the Symlink is created.

My questions are,

1. Do we need to remove the file from the host system?
2. How the Symlink is created between the files?

Kindly excuse if my understanding is inaccurate.

Thank you,
KK

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375350/autoware----sharing-files-between-the-host-system-and-ade/) by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on ROS Answers with karma: 262 on 2021-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. No, keep it on the host since it gets mounted within ADE

   1. The `adehome` folder exists on the host machine, and is mounted inside the Docker container (ADE)
   2. The ADE CLI tool knows to mount this folder within the container because of the `.adehome` file that the docs also tell us to make
2. There isn't a symlink, but rather `adehome` gets mounted within the Docker container (ADE)

   1. Files that you want to have persist across multiple instances (or even persist across restarting ADE) should exist within `adehome`
   2. So clone your reops, store your sample data, etc. within `.adehome`

---

Originally posted by [ltbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41228/ltbj/) with karma: 26 on 2021-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-04-05**:
Thanks for the response.
That's what I was thinking too, and noticed as well.
Apparently section "Sharing files between the host system and ADE" is not needed, since it is already done by ADE.

**Comment by [ltbj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41228/ltbj/) on 2021-04-07**:
True, for ADE it's not required to map the `.basrc` and other files mentioned in the original link, just a helpful hint. Glad I could help!

**Comment by [kk2105](https://answers.ros.org/users/36026/kk2105/) on 2021-04-07**:
Yep, Thank you.